# Apache logs deleted

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

I just tried to delete log files of apache since i am learning to use apachetop and need clear log files.

I ran a command `sudo rm -rf /var/log/apache2/*` and now there is no apache2 folder inside log folder.

I tried access some localhost sites to see if its generated automatically but it is not.

Now my apachetop is not running and it says

`opening /var/log/apache/access.log: No such file or directory`

How will i get back my log files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not answer the question of how to get your log files back, but instead help you get `apachetop` running again.

Have you tried restarting the apache server?  Have you tried accessing the site?  The later of these two suggestions is sure to populate the `access.log` file with an entry.

I'm a bit confused because you've described two different log directories, but if you're still having issues:

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/apache/
sudo mkdir /var/log/apache2/
sudo touch /var/log/apache/access.log /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

You may need to give the apache user read and write access to the files:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/apache
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/apache2
```

---

In the future, do not use `rm` since the software that uses that log expects it to exist. If you would like to make the file empty again, you could:

```
sudo > /var/log/access.log
```

This retains permissions and makes sure Apache does not error out during the time the log was not there.

Comment: sudo is required. Plus added something extra.

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed that you would be running `apachetop` as the apache user and run the commands as the apache user.  I'm updating the answer to allow sudo.

Comment: sorry I already did that :D Hope you dont mind.

Comment: Thanks its working. Restarting doesn't work but the mkdir and touch stuff worked :)